# Function Overloading on jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, overloading

I'm trying to add a method to a jQuery object that has the same name (but different parameter set) as another method.

What I've got so far:

```
jQuery.fn.insertBefore = function(elem, duration)
{
    this.css("display", "none");
    this.insertBefore(elem);
    this.toggle(duration);
}
```

However, this code (specifically the `this.insertBefore(where);` line) calls this same function, and not the [jQuery `insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) function, as desired. What do I need to do in order to add this function to the jQuery object, and have it overload (not overwrite) the existing function?

**EDIT: Solution**

```
(function ($)
{
    var oldInsertBefore = $.fn.insertBefore;
    jQuery.fn.insertBefore = function(elem, duration)
    {
        if (duration === undefined)
        {
            oldInsertBefore.call(this, elem);
            return;
        }

        this.css("display", "none");
        this.insertBefore(elem);
        this.toggle(duration);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You back up original function before overwriting. Something like this:

```
(function($){
    var oldInsertBefore = $.fn.insertBefore;
    jQuery.fn.insertBefore = function(elem, duration)
    {
        oldInsertBefore.apply(this, arguments);
        this.css("display", "none");
        this.insertBefore(elem);
        this.toggle(duration);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would this call the rest of the new `insertBefore` function every time? Or would it somehow be able to tell when to call the old one vs. the new one?

Comment: After this code executes, original `insertBefore` will be replaced. You, in your replaced version, decide when to call original version.

Comment: I would apply something like `if( typeof duration == 'undefined' ) { oldInsertBefore.apply(this, arguments); return; }`

Answer (score 4):

you can use `$.sub()`

```
(function($){
    var sub$ = $.sub();

    sub$.fn.insertBefore = function(where, duration) {
       this.css("display", "none");
       this.insertBefore(where);
       this.toggle(duration);
    }

    /* you can use this plugin in this scope or you could also
       return sub$ and call the plugin outside */
})(jQuery);
```

description of `$.sub()`:

> Creates a new copy of jQuery whose properties and methods can be modified without affecting the original jQuery object.

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/

Answer (score 0):

From a technical perspective JavaScript doesn't let you do define separate functions with the same name, but different arguments. You can only have one function with the same name, though it doesn't care how many arguments come through. All of the solutions posted above take advantage of that, but just end up renaming the original function and calling it. **Unless there's a really good reason I'd suggest giving your custom method a different name so that it doesn't conflict with the existing function.** Imagine someone else trying to add to your code-base and not realizing that a standard jQuery method was overwritten.

Your own method can accept any number of arguments, which can be accessed via the `arguments` object. You can do things like `arguments.length` or just check if your arguments exist to figure out how many / which arguments were passed, (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

It's more standard in jQuery to just pass in an options object when you're making a custom plugin, as explained [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options).

Why are you trying to do this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a solution to overcome some issue I landed here but found out that I never need overloading in any kind. Using jQuery in an own JS-class I've this code:

```js
class myClass
{
    appendMessage(elementObj, message) {
        ...
    }

    appendOrReplaceMessage(elementObj, message) {
        let that = this;
        let elObj = elementObj;
        let msg = message;
        if (elementObj.parent().find('span.error').length) {
            this.disableNextButton(elementObj);
            elementObj.parent().find('span.error').each(function(index, element) {
                $(element).hide({
                    duration: 300,
                    complete: (function() {
                        $(element).remove();
                        that.appendMessage(elObj, msg);
                    })
                })
            });
        } else {
            this.appendMessage(elementObj, message);
        }
    }
}
```

The challenge in this code was that inside the `each`-function the variable `this` has another meaning than outside. So I couldn't use the context of the outer class to call the method `this.appendMessage()`. After adding the declarations inside the method `appendOrReplaceMessage()` I could use the outer object as `that` and the declared variables also are all available inside the `each`-function.

This doesn't answer the question but shows perhaps a way to circumvent the problem.

---

**Related to the problem in the question** it keeps to mention that the jQuery-function `before()` allows using a function as callback, while this option is not given in the jquery-function `insertBefore()`. Using the right function is essential to avoid the over-complicated code obviously.
So the code of the question could be used like this, some adjustments have to be made probably to get it working like desired:

```js
before((function(index){
        this.css("display", "none");
        this.insertBefore(elem);
        this.toggle(duration);
}));
```

My first codeblock beside explanation might be helpful to get the values of the variables `elem` and `duration` inside the `before()` function.

[jQuery API - before()](https://api.jquery.com/before/)
[jQuery API - insertBefore()](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)